# Transforming CountVectorizer with entropy (log-entropy) / sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, entropy, lsa

I would like to try out some variations around Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA) with scikit-learn. Besides pure frequency counts from `CountVectorizer()` and the weighted result of `TfidfTransformer()`, I'd like to test weighting by entropy (and log-entropy) ([used in the original papers and reported to perform very well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing#Mathematics_of_LSI)).

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I know Gensim has an implementation (`LogEntropyModel()`) but would prefer to stick with scikit-learn.

Comment: Well, you need to implement that formula as a transformer or tie scikit-learn and Gensim together. Which part is given you trouble?

Comment: Hi, I haven't started yet... so no trouble so far. I am just asking for suggestions.

Comment: I think the scikit-learn mailing list is more appropriate for this kind of question.